# RE-Stream flash video from server to clients

Tags: java, servlets, video, streaming, ip-camera

I have an ipcamera that whenever multiple of users are connecting to it it becomes too slow.
I was thinking about getting the stream from the camera with my server and multiple of clients should be able to stream from the server instead of the poor ipcamera.

i set up a quick and dirty servlet just too see if it works :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/x-shockwave-flash")
public String getVideoStream(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

logger.info("Start");

                       // An IPcamera stream example
URL url = new URL("http://www.earthcam.com/swf/ads5.swf");
URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();


OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
InputStream in = yc.getInputStream();
String mimeType = "application/x-shockwave-flash";  
byte[] bytes = new byte[100000];
int bytesRead;

response.setContentType(mimeType);

while ((bytesRead = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
}

logger.info("End");
```

I believe this might work, my problem right now is that :

```
bytesRead = in.read(bytes)
```

reads only 61894 bytes and that's it :(  why is that happening? am i trying to get the stream wrong?

btw: i tried to do this with xuggler, but i had an error that compressed-SWF not supported.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly. I just fetched ads5.swf from your server and it is, indeed, 61894 bytes in length. The problem you're facing is that the SWF file is just the movie player. After being downloaded, the player then fetches the video stream from the server. By default (if this is some kind of turn-key streaming solution), it's probably trying to get the stream from the same server where the SWF comes from.